# Using $.post to send basic JSON to php, with a callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

My problem basically is that I cannot figure out the proper syntax (never used JSON before), both on the js and PHP side but I think I can figure the PHP side out myself once I figure out the js.

Logical goal: send JSON data storing variable id# and constant string 'del' , receive JSON data that is contains success/error information, and then based on success/error, echo results into different html. **I am most interested in learning the javascript code on sending and processing received json**, I think the PHP handling should be more straightforward to figure out on my own (hopefully).

**edit** -- when i say success/error, i want that to be determined in the PHP code and not a TRUE hard error. so maybe it's better to think of it as just, an `if` statement in the callback function portion of the jQuery.

```
$(".admin_ru_delete_button").click(function() { //this code is not working
    id = ($(this).attr("id"));
    dataJson = { "id":id, "type":"del" };
    $.post(
        'ajax/justPosted_AJAX.php',
        dataJson,
        function(data){
            //$("#admin_errors").html('');
            //$("#admin_success").html('');
        }
      , "json");
  return false;
});
```

Thanks a lot for your time/help!

Comment: Per the [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) docs, your function defined in your `$.post` call is a success handler which will be called if your PHP returns a document without an error code. The docs have more info on failure handlers if you want to use HTTP status to control success/failure, otherwise, the `data` in your success handler could be a JSON doc like `{"errState": false, "somekey": {...}}` which you could then check in your success handler with `data["errState"]`.

Comment: Check the response in Firebug Net Panel or Webkit Network panel!

Comment: I know this will sound obvious but... Did you import jQuery into the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is converted from a javascript object to POST variables - JSON has nothing to do with this (except for the PHP -> JS part).

```
if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['type'])) {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'id' => $_POST['id']));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'error' => 'type missing'));
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'error' => 'id missing'));
}
```

and in your callback (which is automatically converted to an object, as you specified the content type "json"):

```
function(data){
    if (data.success) {
        alert('Yay! The ID I sent was ' + data.id);
    } else {
        alert(data.error);
    }
}
```

If you want an error when JSON is not returned you can use `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax(
    'ajax/justPosted_AJAX.php',
    {
        dataType: 'json',
        data: dataJson,
        success: function(data){
            if (data.success) {
                alert('Yay! The ID I sent was ' + data.id);
            } else {
                alert(data.error);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('The AJAX call failed: ' + textStatus + ' / ' + errorThrown);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: He said: "I am most interested in learning the javascript code on sending and processing received json"

Comment: @WayneWhitty Yet he added that he didn't know the exact PHP but thought it might have to be JSON decoded which was not the case. I've added a description of how to handle JSON both from PHP and from JS.

Comment: Thank you for the PHP/js code that will save me some time I'm sure. At this point the main issue is still that my js `$.post` code is not sending data to the PHP file properly/at all.

Comment: @HC_ Why do you think it doesn't send it properly? What does a packet inspector (such as Firebug/Chrome's developers tools/Fiddler2) tell you that it's sending?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Chrome said nothing in the console >< that's mainly why I came here: no error reporting to work from.

Comment: @HC_ Check out the "Network" tab and see what it sends/receives from the call. It'll show you the response code, response content, response headers, request headers, request variables etc. You should see the AJAX request as soon as you press the button.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Ah cool -- apparently it is calling the php file. Right now it's simply doing `echo 'hi';` and it didn't show up -- is it possible that since I specified json in the javascript datatype, I can no longer just test output using simple echos?

Comment: @HC_ When you specify JSON manually it will always try to convert it to a JSON object. If it can't then it will not call your callback.

Comment: @HC_ Check my edit on how to fix this (using `$.ajax` instead).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Got it to work! Thank you so much, guess the problem was in my PHP, contrary to my earlier thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

Javascript

```
$(".admin_ru_delete_button").click(function() { 
    id = ($(this).attr("id"));
    $.ajax(
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: 'ajax/justPosted_AJAX.php',
        data: { "id":id, "type":"del" },
        success: function(data){
            $("#admin_success").html(data[1] +" "+ data[2]);
        }
        error: function(data){
            console.Log("Error in ajax");
    });
  return false;
});
```

This is assuming you are returning JSONObject/JSONArray from PHP using `json_encode($array)`.

Comment: Ummm.. [`$.post` doesn't accept `success` and `error`?](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Oh yes, I wrote that in haste. Thanks for the nudge. He should use a simple $.ajax call if he wants to handle `success` and `error`.